# HAProxy1.7 forward client IP to backend

Tags: java, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I'm trying to forward source/client_ip(%ci) that reaches haproxy to the applicaion using X_FORWARDED_FOR.

HA-Proxy version 1.7.9 2017/08/18

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 info
    daemon
    user vcap
    group vcap
    maxconn 64000
    spread-checks 4

defaults
    maxconn 64000
    option http-server-close
    option httplog
    option forwardfor

frontend http-in
    mode http
    bind :80
    log global
    option forwardfor except 127.0.0.1

frontend https-in
    mode http
    log global
    bind :443 ssl crt /data/haproxy/ssl/server.pem
    option forwardfor except 127.0.0.1
    use_backend https-backend
    
    http-request set-header SSL_CLIENT_CERT_USER         %{+Q}[ssl_c_s_dn(cn)]
    http-request set-header SSL_CLIENT_CERT         %{+Q}[ssl_c_der,base64]
    http-request set-header SSL_CLIENT_CERT_USED    %[ssl_c_used] if no_user_cert

backend https-backend
    mode http
    log global
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor header X-Client
```

Java app does the following:

```
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
 
if (ipAddress == null) {
    ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

Having the above config in place, I get haproxy's IP in the application log and not the actual source IP.

Adding set-header in the frontend or backend or on both sides did not help:
`http-request set-header X-CLIENT-IP %[src]`.

Am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should update to the lates 1.7 version https://www.haproxy.org/bugs/bugs-1.7.9.html

You define `option forwardfor header X-Client` therefore your App should get the `X-Client` header.

```
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_CLIENT");
```

Doc: [option forwardfor](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4-option%20forwardfor)

Comment: Thanks Aleksandar, instead of code change, I tried `option forwardfor` instead of `option forwardfor header X-Client` which has "X-Forwarded-For" by default and that gave backend server's IP. But when I replace the header with `header X-Client`, it gives haproxy IP. So, do you think it is a bug in 1.7?

Comment: I don't know because I haven't used `header ...` option